# Django: Trying to implement a file upload progress bar

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to implement a progress bar for my file upload. However, I kept on getting 405 Method not allowed error. I am very new to Ajax and jQuery so it would be great it someone can help me out.

Currently my file upload class-based view is working fine.

This is my class-based view:

```
class UploadLessonView(CreateView):
model = Lesson
fields = ['title', 'file']  
template_name = 'store/upload_lesson.html'
success_url = '/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.post = get_object_or_404(Post, 
pk=self.kwargs.get('post_id'))
    return super(UploadLessonView, self).form_valid(form)   

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('lesson_uploaded', kwargs={'post_id' : 
self.object.post_id})
```

This is my html template

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="/static/store/upload.js"></script>
<div id="main">      
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form | crispy }}
        <button href = "{% url 'store-home' %}" class="btn 
btn-secondary" type="submit" >Upload File</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

    $.ajax({
        xhr : function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {

                if (e.lengthComputable) {

                    console.log('Bytes Loaded: ' + e.loaded);
                    console.log('Total Size: ' + e.total);
                    console.log('Percentage Uploaded: ' + (e.loaded / e.total))

                }
            });

            return xhr;
        },
        type :'post',
        url : '/',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken':  csrftoken },
        data: formData,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        success : function() {
            alert('File uploaded!');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: is there a default `POST` action/method at `{% url 'store-home' %}/` ? If not, you need to include the method name in the `url` for your ajax call.

Comment: @mjw Hi thanks for the reply! do you mean that in my js file, the url should be url : 'post'?

Comment: Your ajax call has several properties. The method type is POST. What i'm asking you is what the service method you're calling should be and if it actually exists at the URL you're attempting to call `url: '/'` -- this implies your ajax call is to a method at the root of your form action URL ` <button href = "{% url 'store-home' %}"` as shown in your markup. Is this what you want or is there a web method name you are missing in the ajax call `url` property?